# Where can I get a small form factor security cables similar to the one that Apple Stores use for their iPhone?

Tags: iphone, security, apple-store

I notice that iPhone antitheft cables that attach on the back side all take up a huge space on the back of the phone.

Are there small form factor ones? Is there a way to get the Apple Store sized smaller security antitheft cables?

Comment: Have you asked at the store? Have you looked for the manufacturers name or asked for it ?

Comment: Also, ugly is relativ :-) Take a look at https://duckduckgo.com/?q=kensington+lock+cable&bext=msl&atb=v105-5__&iax=images&ia=images and similar searches, there is a huge variety of cables out there.

Comment: If you're a Reseller you should get them from your Distributor.

Comment: @patrix have you seen a good kensington security cable for an iphone

Comment: @patrix updated question to be less opinion based

Comment: @KevinGrabher i'm just someone who wants to show off an iPhone app at Makerfaire

Comment: @ina There's no official way to get Apples security cable, Apple offers it just to their resellers. Ask some stores I guess..

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the iPhone part .-)

Comment: The product you are looking for is called a *security tether*.  It's not a specialized product only available to iPhone vendors.  A quick search on [Amazon](https://amzn.to/2JUP2YN) and you will find a bunch of them